# Commonly used Class definition library for Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, oop

Is there a commonly used JavaScript library for creating extendable classes?

I've encountered a number of libraries that have their own concept of classes (e.g., React and Backbone), but they don't seem to be mutually compatible and most are based on MV* pattern.

Is there something out there that is commonly used for more generic class definition? Ideally, something with classes that can be subclassed and automatic method binding.

Comment: Not so much a library as an explanation of "classes" in JavaScript: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch4.md

Comment: It's probably a bit off-topic, but you might want to have a look at TypeScript: http://www.typescriptlang.org/

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a nested-function class by own nature. You can try without any library this options:

```
 var myClass = function() {
     this.myPublicProperty = null;
     var myPrivateProperty = null;

     this.myPublicFunction = function() {
         //stuff
     };

     var myPrivateFunction = function() {
         //stuff
     }; 
 };
```

Or you can try prototyped javascript

```
 var myClass = function() { this.var = null ; }
 myClass.prototype.newFunction = function() {};
 myClass.prototype.newProperty = null;
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm familiar with the basics of how to create these constructor functions and the use of prototypes, but it's missing a lot of standard class functionality, like inheritance, access to a `super` method/object, and method binding.

Comment: you can have inheritance and supermethod access if you use properly the prototype. I want to help you more, but I need to know your idea to develop properly my answer.

Comment: What idea do you need to know? If you have an example of how to do these things, please share.